# Justification for divisor of $(2n)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, alternative-proof, solution-verification

I was reading the following [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272482/1-s2.0-S0022314X12X00040/1-s2.0-S0022314X12000479/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKX%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCICxA916UxYzF8YyfTDRbOc5EYAy0HsUxudxOmiy2kH6RAiATYRN1ADjOc4V9VcrqZ%2BmH%2BC7olxAd45JLtuzEzweSdiq0AwhNEAIaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMa4K0VLG1xaSe7maAKpEDJSuF5LETtx5l5QM%2BH%2FizKH4F6hL%2Fz0haoMLuc0IzyLT4Wokyb7Qk%2FJb1IOtW0vdX%2Bdw1JDZMD3BxtcfpZuV%2FcwkTgXuh2i6dfETIq05vJ1dgnvgOwIEIcpfbfL96OBM%2FKmw5SvVsidVuQiXVT7UCpJhVOJFZDpiJkIqZx1sf%2BXvc0isBkb8mPe0PopPgALi0EJgDQewfWTZqXp5%2Fyc9AJtLxpGNI2LDOHyR6QSpnpwI%2FSxVwZxo7JfL8nU4Vqnl4RKveIn97zGGLkJ8qkZ9n%2BHxh%2FcvBhuB1FRzGknMAA73GkhBbfW7Y7FxMfEYtYj7xq42D%2Fwowtu0Mi%2FIeaZM9gpu5UqAdhaEgi2C10ODcTf1xt%2FzfKqdrkEgNN0HaFezKS%2B3LEmChLoXhWyQ%2FeTtdCZxg2O7x45lr5MUYETNttBfeOxQIVih8E58GMJcPk4td5vUAuJYkiwbjU4HPxCWY88o2UNTiCgHLH6bchfmQPyqMbEJ2u1GvxLUyppY6qyJLV0WweDt9xHqISHCxu8s6%2BfMws9rc8QU67AGE1eE9ntKhNl29J9Nr04htsgRZI9oAWko96HTB2oSTkPHf0QjX61ehHFJcHxDHnF%2B7gcSG0Le0%2BLrbnhkYFtkOQMRR%2FoJkZCFWejDxMKqs3a%2FtapdH5FSdwarpftCaxYJ4zynlQ4r3YtlHJePjcDrMxLUeTGZbWCg%2F8sUGVEfFOeJmk44NFp99tMNbruU6wHzIabP9psibCrv5MdBr3nJUYSxI9DA6NZL8ox1%2B5dzQN4lF%2FSSo1bsCHDcYIMHjcN0McfHCJehaL%2ByTAoyfP80Aiyr00wuda5ItnH2gGrd4IOJ83N9P8cPaaxMvZg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200202T214113Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3MEQHJW3%2F20200202%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=27f821a38e5b32f90acfbaff1d661bffa1d4ea075d8c1a679675a84a2a0141ff&hash=7c42940cf637087ce1139aaee0a71b12e7b723f645c41987eefd3dfc1bf90485&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022314X12000479&tid=spdf-ddc9ffd7-88aa-4cc7-b734-c3c2e1190854&sid=f8b3899c8d00f842b148858294398e562aeegxrqa&type=client) and saw the comment *(on page 2)* that with p a prime $p \geq 5 $ and $p=\frac{n+2}{2}$ that $p^3\parallel(2n)!$ (where in this case the double pipe notation means that if $p^a\parallel t$ then $p^a\mid t$ but $p^{a+1} \nmid t$)

I am sure that there is some reasonably simple justification for this, but I am not so clever. My justification is quite long winded, and I can't really bring myself to move on without knowing the more simple justification for this fact. **Primarily, I was curious if anyone could please provide a more simple answer than mine.**

I will provide the way I justified this:

$$
\mu_q(m!)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left \lfloor \frac{m}{q^k}\right \rfloor
$$

is the highest power of q which divides m!, applying this to the above problem

$$
\mu_p((2n)!)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left \lfloor \frac{2n}{\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^k} \right \rfloor < 2n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{(n+1)^k}=2n\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{n+2}}-1\right)=4
$$

So that $\mu_p((2n)!)<4$, and therefore $p^4 \nmid (2n)!$

Now consider only the first term of the sum $\mu_p((2n)!)$,

$$
\left  \lfloor \frac{4n}{n+2}\right \rfloor
$$

Since $p\ge5$: $n \ge 8$, so taking n to be 8

$$
\left  \lfloor \frac{4\times8}{8+2}\right \rfloor=\left  \lfloor \frac{32}{10}\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor 3.2 \right \rfloor=3
$$

Now again considering only the first term and keeping in mind that floor does not change the sign here

$$
\frac{d}{dn} \frac{4n}{(n+2)}=\frac{8}{(n+2)^2}
$$

So that the first term is an increasing function of n, now since $$3\le \mu_p((2n)!) < 4$$
and $\mu_p((2n)!)$ must be an integer, then $\mu_p((2n)!)=3$. Therefore 
$$
p^3\parallel(2n)!
$$

If I did anything stupid please feel free to let me know. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p>5$ be a prime number, and let $n=2p-2$ (which is equivalent to $p=\frac{n+2}2$).  Then $p$, $2p$, and $3p$ are all less than $2n=4p-4$, but $4p$ is not.  Therefore, $(2n)!$ has exactly three terms that are multiples of $p$.  Moreover, since $p>5$, all three terms are less than $p^2$, so each term carries exactly "one power of $p$".  Thus, $p^3\parallel(2n)!$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel very stupid for not noticing that. It helps a lot.